# Spring autowire interface

Tags: java, spring, interface, autowired

I have an Interface IMenuItem

```
public interface IMenuItem {

    String getIconClass();
    void setIconClass(String iconClass);

    String getLink();
    void setLink(String link);

    String getText();
    void setText(String text);

}
```

Then I have a implementation for this interface

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MenuItem implements IMenuItem {

    private String iconClass;
    private String link;
    private String text;

    public MenuItem(String iconClass, String link, String text) {
        this.iconClass = iconClass;
        this.link = link;
        this.text = text;
    }

    //setters and getters

}
```

Is there any way to create multiple instances of MenuItem from a configuration class, using only the IMenuItem interface? with @autowired or something ? Also is it possible to autowire by specifying the arguments of the constructor ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`@Autowired` is actually perfect for this scenario. You can either autowire a specific class (implemention) or use an interface.

Consider this example:

```
public interface Item {
}

@Component("itemA")
public class ItemImplA implements Item {
}

@Component("itemB")
public class ItemImplB implements Item {
}
```

Now you can choose which one of these implementations will be used simply by choosing a name for the object according to the `@Component` annotation value

Like this:

```
@Autowired
private Item itemA; // ItemA

@Autowired
private Item itemB // ItemB
```

For creating the same instance multiple times, you can use the @Qualifier annotation to specify which implementation will be used:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("itemA")
private Item item1;
```

In case you need to instantiate the items with some specific constructor parameters, you will have to specify it an XML configuration file. Nice tutorial about using qulifiers and autowiring can be found [HERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_qualifier_annotation.htm).

Comment: I have only one implementation (MenuItem). I want to create for example 3 MenuItems, but only through the interface.

Comment: See the edited answer, hope it helps. You will need the qualifier annotation

Answer (score 3):

i believe half of job is done by your `@scope` annotation , if there is not any-other implementation of ImenuItem interface in your project below will create multiple instances

```
@Autowired
private IMenuItem menuItem
```

but if there are multiple implementations, you need to use `@Qualifer` annotation .

```
@Autowired
@Qualifer("MenuItem")
private IMenuItem menuItem
```

this will also create multiple instances

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to instanciate multiple menuItem's with given parameters ? I @autowired to use the constructor in MenuItem, not the default empty constructor.

Comment: you need to annotate constructor with @Autowired . but it did not work with primitive data type , you need to  create another Pojo with String iconClass, String link, String text and inject that Pojo as bean

Comment: Why will it create multiple instances when only one implementation is there for `IMenuItem` interface?