# How to instantiate a Class/Bean in Spring passing parameter in constructor

Tags: java, spring

I need to Autowire service interface in my controller, passing parameter logcode in not default service constructor

```
 @Controller
    public class FooController {

        private Foo foo;

        @Autowired
        private FooService fooService //(I like passe parameter here);

    }

Here's my Service:
```

I need to Autowire service interface in my controller, passing parameter logcode in not default service constructor

```
 @Service
    public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

        @Autowired
        private FooDAO fooDAO;

    public FooServiceImpl(String pLogCode)
    {

    }

        @Transactional
        public void addFoo(Foo foo) {
            fooDAO.addFoo(foo);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, to get you an idea for my project architect. i have maven multi module project. desktop; web app, android all this project (modules) must be passed this parameter "logCode" to service layer and this service layer passses the same parameter to DAO module.

Comment: Thank you for that response, to get an idea on my project architect. i have multiple maven project module. desk; web app, android all these projects (modules) must pass this parameter "logCode" that is the service layer and the service layer passses the same parameter to DAO module. for example in the case of the Web application when a user connects it saves this setting websession, so my parameter is dynamic.
How in this case ?Thank you

Comment: Where does the value of `pLogCode` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Passing arguments when autowiring interfaces it's only possible in XML config. Simmilar question is here:
[Spring autowire interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138830/spring-autowire-interface)

Comment: Thank you for that response, to get an idea on my project architect. i have multiple maven project module. desk; web app, android all these projects (modules) must pass this parameter "logCode" that is the service layer and the service layer passses the same parameter to DAO module. for example in the case of the Web application when a user connects it saves this setting websession, so my parameter is dynamic.
How in this case ?Thank you