# Field vehicleRepository required a bean of type ..VehicleInterface that could not be found

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jpa, oracle11g

I'm trying to @autowire repository reference from Service implementation class but still I'm getting bean not found error

I've already tried moving App.java file in the parent

App.java

```
package com.trucker;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(App.class,args);

    }
}
```

VehicleService.java

```
package com.trucker.service;

import com.trucker.entity.Vehicle;
import com.trucker.repository.VehicleRepositoryInterface;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class VehicleService implements VehicleServiceI {

    @Autowired
    VehicleRepositoryInterface vehicleRepository;

    @Override
    public Vehicle addVehicles(Vehicle vehicle) {
        System.out.println(vehicle);
        return vehicleRepository.save(vehicle);
    }

}
```

VehicleRepositoryInterface.java

```
package com.trucker.repository;

import com.trucker.entity.Vehicle;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

public interface VehicleRepositoryInterface extends CrudRepository<Vehicle,String> {

}
```

VehicleController.java

```
package com.trucker.controller;

import com.trucker.entity.Vehicle;
import com.trucker.service.VehicleServiceI;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class VehicleController {

    @Autowired
    VehicleServiceI vehicleService;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/vehicles", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String addVehicles(@RequestBody Vehicle vehicle) {
        System.out.println("************IN THE CONTROLLER************"+vehicle);
        vehicleService.addVehicles(vehicle);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Vehicle.java

```
package com.trucker.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    String vin;
    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    int redlineRpm;
    int maxFuelVolume;
    Timestamp lastServiceDate;

    public String getVin() {
        return vin;
    }

    public void setVin(String vin) {
        this.vin = vin;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public int getRedlineRpm() {
        return redlineRpm;
    }

    public void setRedlineRpm(int redlineRpm) {
        this.redlineRpm = redlineRpm;
    }

    public int getMaxFuelVolume() {
        return maxFuelVolume;
    }

    public void setMaxFuelVolume(int maxFuelVolume) {
        this.maxFuelVolume = maxFuelVolume;
    }

    public Timestamp getLastServiceDate() {
        return lastServiceDate;
    }

    public void setLastServiceDate(Timestamp lastServiceDate) {
        this.lastServiceDate = lastServiceDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehicle{" +
                "vin='" + vin + '\'' +
                ", make='" + make + '\'' +
                ", model='" + model + '\'' +
                ", year=" + year +
                ", redlineRpm=" + redlineRpm +
                ", maxFuelVolume=" + maxFuelVolume +
                ", lastServiceDate=" + lastServiceDate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
application.properties
server.port=8084
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=system
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Directory Structure:

```
src
src/main
src/main/resources/application.properties
src/main/java
src/main/java/com.trucker
src/main/java/com.trucker/App.java
src/main/java/com.trucker.controller
src/main/java/com.trucker.controller.VehicleController
src/main/java/com.trucker.entity.Vehicle
src/main/java/com.trucker.repository
src/main/java/com.trucker.repository.VehicleRepositoryInterface
src/main/java/com.trucker.service
src/main/java/com.trucker.service.vehicleService
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post it has clear answers

[Spring boot autowiring an interface with multiple implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766013/spring-boot-autowiring-an-interface-with-multiple-implementations)

or

[Spring autowire interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138830/spring-autowire-interface)